# LWJGL Display.update() slowing down application

Tags: java, performance, lwjgl, frame-rate

I'm using [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org) for a Java Application and I seem to have a problem with `Display.update()`. If I remove `Display.update()` from the loop I get an FPS at around 7000000 - 9000000. With `Display.update()` I get only around 200 - 300 FPS. Is this normal?

I'm using a Macbook Air 2013 with 1,7 GHz i7, 8GB RAM and Intel HD Graphics 5000.

Here is the code I have:

**Main.java**

```
class Main{
    private static Time time;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initDisplay();
        initGL();
        time = new Time();
        gameLoop();
        cleanUp();
    }

    private static void gameLoop(){
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            Display.update();
            time.updateFPS();
        }
    }

    private static void initDisplay(){
        try{
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
            Display.setVSyncEnabled(false);
            Display.create();
            Display.setTitle("Application Title");
        }catch(LWJGLException e){
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static void initGL(){
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    private static void cleanUp(){
        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

**Time.java**

```
public class Time {
    long lastFrame;
    long lastFPS;
    int fps;

    public Time(){
        getDelta();
        lastFPS = getTime();
    }
    public long getTime() {
        return (Sys.getTime() * 1000) / Sys.getTimerResolution();
    }

    public int getDelta() {
        long time = getTime();
        int delta = (int) (time - lastFrame);
        lastFrame = time;

        return delta;
    }
    public void updateFPS() {
        if (getTime() - lastFPS > 1000) {
            Display.setTitle(Integer.toString(fps));

            fps = 0;
            lastFPS += 1000;
        }
        fps++;
    }
    public int getFPS(){ return fps;}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is correct. You should get a massive FPS jump by not having `Display.update()` because the application is literally doing nothing other than iterating through a loop and counting the time it takes to perform that iteration.

It's hard to see this now since you don't have any components render to the `Display`, but not calling `Display.update()` would prevent anything from being rendered in the display window.

**In short, you need `Display.update()` to actually do anything in LWJGL.**

Other than that, you have a good framework for managing time in your application. I would suggest adding a 'throttle' to cap the FPS. Running the game at max speed makes you unable to standardize time and hurts your processor.

Comment: you can also use [Display.sync(fps)](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#sync(int)) to adjust your framerate.